# `Vue3 - Vite` project alias src to @ not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I have installed the project with `vue3 - vite` importing a component like

```
import Component from '../../../../components/Component.vue'
```

i just want to alias the src folder and do

```
import Component from '@/components/Component.vue'
```

this is my vite.config.js

```js
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

/**
 * https://vitejs.dev/config/
 * @type {import('vite').UserConfig}
 */
export default {
    plugins: [
        vue({
            template: {
                compilerOptions: {
                    // ...
                }
            }
        })
    ]
}
```

am i missing something? what else should i do?

Comment: have you tried addiing `jsconfig.json`? I didnt know `jsconfig` will work with Vue Vite or not but usually I use this with Vue 2

Comment: I solved this issue adding this in paths array inside my  `tsconfig.json` file: `"@/*": ["./src/*"]`

Answer (score 163):

## Update 2023

Here is what worked for me (finally):

*ViteConfig:*

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "url";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      { find: '@', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)) },
      { find: '@assets', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/shared/assets', import.meta.url)) },
      { find: '@cmp', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/shared/cmp', import.meta.url)) },
      { find: '@stores', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/shared/stores', import.meta.url)) },
      { find: '@use', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/shared/use', import.meta.url)) },
    ],
  },
});
```

*TSConfig:*

```json
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@assets/*": ["./src/shared/assets/*"],
      "@cmp/*": ["./src/shared/cmp/*"],
      "@stores/*": ["./src/shared/stores/*"],
      "@use/*": ["./src/shared/use/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

## Update 2022

This solution comes by default from when creating a new project with `npm init vue@latest`

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "url";

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
});
```

In components use `@/`:

```html
<script setup>
import HelloWorld from "@/components/HelloWorld.vue";
</script>
```

---

---

This is what worked for me:

```js
import path from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@/': `${path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')}/`
    }
  }
})
```

Then in components:

```js
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />
  <HelloWorld msg="Hello Vue 3 + Vite" />
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I get a warning when starting the dev server:
Unrestricted file system access to "C:/Projects/my-vite-project/src/main.ts"
For security concerns, accessing files outside of serving allow list will be restricted by default in the future version of Vite. Refer to https://vitejs.dev/config/#server-fs-allow for more details.

Comment: Heads up: I needed to add a slash before the @ for it to work, because otherwise ["that's considered a package"](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/279#issuecomment-636110354). So like this: `import HelloWorld from '/@/components/HelloWorld.vue'`

Comment: This worked for me and I got to remove `vite-tsconfig-paths`! Thank you. I think you still need to keeping mapping in tsconfig.json for editor intellisense.

Comment: I have a problem doing this. When I change the template of the imported component with alias path it doesn't hot reload on save nor on hard reload. I have to restart the vite server to see the change

Comment: Holy molly, the 2023 update worked ! thanks

Comment: God bless you and blessed be the fruit of thy mother's womb.

Comment: How can I use dynamically switching between prod and env mode in aliases? I tried this here: resolve: { alias: [ {find: '@auth', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL(
`./src/api/auth/${process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'server' : 'mock'}`, import.meta.url))} ] ] ... and in my tsconfig.json I added "paths": {"@/*": ["./src/*", "./dist/*"],"@auth/*": ["./src/api/auth/*"] } and I still get a compiler error that my auth service cannot be resolved ts(2307). Any ideas?

Answer (score 122):

In the `vite.config.js` file write the below code blocks

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: If using vite v2.5.0 or higher `'@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),` . Add `.` before `/src`

Answer (score 38):

**Vue 3 Vite TypeScript**

**vite.config.ts**

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    },
  }
})
```

To remove warnings and add hint to download with `@/`

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*", "./dist/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: nice. thanks you. I alway has warnings by TS because I set the path to `"@/*": ["./src"]`. haha

Answer (score 11):

Unlike `webpack`, `Vite` doesn't have `@` aliased to `src` by default. There is discussion of this at the following issue: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/279

Ultimately you need to create an alias:

```
// vite.config.js 
module.exports = {
  alias: {
    '/@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
  }
}

// Your config 
export default {
  alias: {
    '/@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
  },
  plugins: [ ... ]
 }
```

Then you need to use `/@` in your files, e.g.:

```
import foo from '/@foo'
```

Comment: I like your answer, but I don't know how to insert it into mine `vite.config.js`

Comment: Have updated the answer to hopefully give the answer for your config file.

Comment: failed to load config from C:\Users\user\PhpstormProjects\prazdnik\vite.config.js

Error while running task C:\Users\user\PhpstormProjects\prazdnik:dev with message 'spawn vite ENOENT'
error when starting dev server:...

Answer (score 8):

I tried most of the above solutions and unfortunately did not work. The following did.

In my jsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

and in my vite.config.js

```
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import path from "path";

import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)), "src"),
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It will be easier If you point the directory without "."(dot) prefix, dont need to use **fileURLToPath** anymore.

*ViteConfig:*

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite"
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue"

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      // instead of writing:
      // fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url))
      // remove "."(dot) prefix from path and write it like below:
      '@': '/src',
      '@assets': '/src/shared/assets',
      '@cmp': '/src/shared/cmp',
      '@stores': '/src/shared/stores',
      '@use': '/src/shared/use'
    }
  },
})
```

*TSConfig:*

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@assets/*": ["./src/shared/assets/*"],
      "@cmp/*": ["./src/shared/cmp/*"],
      "@stores/*": ["./src/shared/stores/*"],
      "@use/*": ["./src/shared/use/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:**
"vite.config" file directory level must be the same as "src folder" otherwise yo must point it with "**../**" prefix in alias.

Answer (score 1):

In my Vite 2.7.x

```
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import path from 'path'
 
...    
...
 resolve: {
   alias: [
      { find: '@', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, './src') },
      { find: '...', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, '...') },
      { find: '...', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, '...') },
      { find: '...', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, '...') },
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my blog post i describe how to configure this with Vite, TypeScript and Jest: https://divotion.com/blog/how-to-configure-import-aliases-in-vite-typescript-and-jest. For Vite change the `vite.config.ts` file to:

```js
// vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import path from "path";

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

## As of Oct 2022

I encountered similar problems to yours, although I'm working on my **React Project** using **Vite** this still works on the **Vue** project too.

This is my **vite.config.ts**:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import path from 'path';
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '/@src-pages': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/pages'),
            '/@src-assets': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets')
        }
    },
    plugins: [vue()]
});
```

**Don't forget to add "/" before your alias name.**

I found this solution from Vite Github Issue: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/279#issuecomment-635646269

Answer (score 0):

### Export path resolve function

#### Problrem

`@/` alias doesn't work in `:src` dynamic attribure, so that you can't resolve asset file path dynamically.

#### Solution

1. In the common ts code, define path resolve function(i.e. `img()`) using `import.meta.url`.
2. Use `img()` in the vue script.

Files

```
/src
  /assets/img/
    logo.png
  Util.ts
  App.vue
```

Util.ts

```
export const srcRoot = import.meta.url;
export function img(name:string){
  return new URL(`./assets/img/${name}.png`, srcRoot)
}
```

App.vue

```
<script>
import {img} from "./Util";
</script>

<template>
<img  :src="img('logo')" />
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

As October 2023,

I am using vite(4.4.5) + vue(3.3.4) + ts(5.0.2).

This is what I had to do when I start a new project.

vite.config.ts

```
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/"),
    },
  },
  plugins: [vue()],
});
```

The code above would make the vue to compile your vue component and typescript classes. You can run npm run dev and you wouldn't see any error and the page would render.

Although your vs code probably is showing the error and also if you run npm run build that would fail.

```
src/App.vue:2:24 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/components/HelloWorld.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.

src/components/test.ts:2:22 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/classes/classA' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

The configuration below does the tricky for me.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
}
```

The code above I didn't need to add Public neither change anything about moduleResolution.

My App.vue component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue'
</script>
```

HelloWolrd.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import myTestClass from '@/components/test';

defineProps<{ msg: string }>()

const count = ref(0)

new myTestClass().myMethod();
```

My test.ts

```
import MyClassA from "@/classes/classA";

export default class myTestClass {
```

Keep in mind vscode configuration as well.
[VS Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7BHI.png)

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work for me and is shorter:

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve('./resources'),
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

Comment: Shorter, don't mean better. Without `__dirname` after compiling and punting to some run environment, bet it won't work.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code in '**vite.config.ts**' or '**vite.config.js**' file

```
import { resolve } from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': resolve(__dirname, './src')
    },
  },
  plugins: [vue()],
})
```