# Vite Vue-3 - project @ not working for srcset

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66515600/1292050) solution to make alias @ work:

My vite.config.js:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import path from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      { find: '@', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') }
    ],
  },
})
```

This works:

```html
<img src="@/assets/logo.png">
```

This doesn't work:

```html
<img src="@/assets/logo.png" srcset="@/assets/logo@2x.png 2x">
```

Here is how my output in browser looks like:

```html
<img
  src="/src/assets/logo.png"
  srcset="/src/views/@/assets/logo@2x.png 2x"
>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `@vue/compiler-sfc` has a bug, introduced in `v3.0.0-beta.9` when [adding support for absolute URLs in `srcset`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/commit/6a0be882d4ce95eb8d8093f273ea0e868acfcd24). This bug bypasses the [transformation that would've resolved the asset URLs in `srcset`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/5eb72630a53a8dd82c2b8a9705c21a8075161a3d/packages/compiler-sfc/src/templateTransformSrcset.ts#L98-L158). (*Reported in GitHub issue [`vuejs/vue-next#4819`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/4819)*)

A workaround I found was to manually create a `srcset` with the asset URLs explicitly resolved:

```html
<template>
  <img :srcset="srcset" />
</template>

<script setup>
import logo2x from '@/assets/logo@2x.png'
import logo3x from '@/assets/logo@3x.png'

const srcset = `${logo2x} 2x, ${logo3x} 3x`
</script>
```

Or using dynamic imports, which may be helpful if you need to update `srcset` dynamically:

```html
<template>
  <img :srcset="srcset" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const srcset = ref(null)
Promise.all([
  import('@/assets/logo@2x.png'),
  import('@/assets/logo@3x.png')
]).then(([{ default: logo2x }, { default: logo3x }]) => {
  srcset.value = `${logo2x} 2x, ${logo3x} 3x`
})
</script>
```

Comment: is this issue know or reported to vite team? will there any easy fix soon?

Comment: @Syed I reported the bug in https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/4819

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the v-binding for `srcset`.

```html
<img 
  src="@/assets/logo.png" 
  :srcset="require('@/assets/logo@2x.png') + ' 2x'"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that did not help. I am getting this error: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: require is not defined` and more over I was looking for solution without using `require()`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are not very specific to keep images in `./src/assets/images` folder, there is a simple fix and that would be to move your images to `./public/assets/image` folder and refer it like:

```
<img src="/assets/images/img-01.png"
     srcset="/assets/images/img-01@2x.png 2x">
```