# vue3 vite alias not working as expected with typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vite

I tried all the answers in below thread and got no luck:

[`Vue3 - Vite` project alias src to @ not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66043612/vue3-vite-project-alias-src-to-not-working)

```
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.vue'],
        alias: [{
            find: '@',
            replacement: resolve(__dirname, 'src')
        }],
    },
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        Components({
            resolvers: [ElementPlusResolver()],
        }),
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Struggled with this issue for several hours, and just solved it several minutes after posting the issue here...

Ts config is also needed:

1. If **path** is not working, please add **baseUrl** config as well.
2. **Restart** the IDE once the configuration has been modified. (IntelliJ has been tested not working if it hasn't been restarted)

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "target": "esnext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ],
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"]
}
```