Import aliasing won't work in Vite (React, Typescript) boilerplate
I installed shadcn/ui into my vite boilerplate following the docs. But the compiler didn't seem to recognize the aliasing.
Note: typescript has more than one config file, namely: tsconfig.json, tsconfig.app.json, and tsconfig.node.json. Initially, the "compilerOptions" option key wasn't defined in the original tsconfig but in the other 2 files instead. So I duplicated it to include the alias config in the original file.
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ]
}

// vite.config.ts
import path from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
});



Did you try to restart the TS server from the VS Code?

If it did not work, you can check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66043612/vue3-vite-project-alias-src-to-not-working

Yes, I did, using CTRL + SHIFT + P shortcut

in vite.config.ts try to put instead of path.resolve(__dirname, "./src") just /src like this         src: '/src',
this is working for me

Thanks for the link. I tried using the most trending answer (with the most votes), it still didn't work. I also tried your last suggestion, nothing yet

The problem was apparently in the tsconfig files. The paths option had to be set on both tsconfig.app.json file and plain tsconfig.json so that the ts compiler resolves the path correcly and for the shadcnui to install the components in the right directory based on the configurations of the plain tsconfig.
//tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ]
}

// tsconfig.app.json
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}


Vite's latest template (v5.*) is working with tsconfig.app.json. tsconfig.app.json overrides or extends tsconfig.json configurations to set configuration for app-specific purposes. To solve this you can follow any of the solution below.

Keep vite.config.ts as it is in the question.

Solution 1
Keep configurations to tsconfig.app.json 's compilerOptions section instead of tsconfig.json.
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
    //...existing configs
}

Solution 2 (Old way)
If you don't want to do app-specific configuration just remove the reference of tsconfig.app.json inside the references section of tsconfig.json and keep everything as it's in the question.
  "references": [
    { "path": "./tsconfig.app.json" }, // ❌ remove this line
    { "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }
  ]

